# LLC in states with customers with and without employees in the state

Tags: united-states, limited-liability-company

I work out of my home office, I do not have a business office setup.

I did register an LLC in the state of Oklahoma where I live.

My question is, two fold:

1. If I hire someone in Utah to do sales for me over the phone, and he
   works out of his home, am I required to register an LLC or file my
   current one as a foreign entity in Utah?
2. If my sales guy, or I, call businesses in, say, Florida, and sell a
   few businesses our services for online work like maybe a website
   design, etc. Are we required to file our LLC In Florida as either a
   new LLC or a foreign one?

-Thanks!

Comment: This may be more apt on http://startups.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I hire someone in Utah to do sales for me over the phone, and he
>   works out of his home, am I required to register an LLC or file my
>   current one as a foreign entity in Utah?

Yes, since you've established presence in Utah. You'll register your current LLC in Utah, no point creating another one.

> If my sales guy, or I, call businesses in, say, Florida, and sell a
>   few businesses our services for online work like maybe a website
>   design, etc. Are we required to file our LLC In Florida as either a
>   new LLC or a foreign one?

No, you need to register where you (your company, including your employees or physical offices) are physically present. You don't need to register in any state you ship products or provide services to. If no-one of your company's employees is present in Florida and you don't have an office/rent a storage there - then you have no presence in Florida. If you actually go there to provide the services - then you do.